# How to prevent Apache directory listings in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I've read quite a bit about this and i'm starting to get a bit confused on which is the right way to do this.

I don't have an `httpd.conf` file, however i do have an `apache2.conf` file located here: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

(notating the directory)

Additionally the standard sites-available here: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

So which file should I add the contents of below?

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

(no need to notate the directory if it goes here, correct?)

Also inside the `000-default.conf` file it has directory like 5 times like so...

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So could I edit one of those or do I have to do something completely different in like `.htaccess`? Which I believe would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can put it anywhere in any of those files.

### But the reason why one puts one thing in one file versus another is up to you.

Okay, so this stuff is confusing when you first encounter it, but it’s simple as well. Here is a breakdown.

First, `httpd.conf` is 100% the same as `apache2.conf`. The only difference is that `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` is what RedHat/CentOS uses and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is what Debian/Ubuntu uses.

Next, what is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` versus `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` versus `/var/www/html/.htaccess`? Good question and here are the answers.

---

### `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

This is the root/parent Apache config file. If you are 100% sure that the Apache server on that machine should never do directory listings no matter what, just set this in there. This will set defaults for the server and all virtual hosts on the machine:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache via `sudo service apache2 restart` and you are good to go.

### `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

This is the virtual host default config for the Apache server. The main difference between `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and this config is this `000-default.conf` is typically the place where people put tweaks and adjustments specific to their server. The benefit is that it is short and sweet and can only be a few lines of config if needed. The negative aspect of this is if you are using virtual hosts, the settings in here would be ignored by another virtual host config. But if you are 100% sure you are only using Apache for one host on your setup, this is fine.

### `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

I personally think this is the best place to do something like that. As long as your main `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is set to `AllowOverride All` (which is what enables `.htaccess`) this will be the simplest to maintain. Mainly because adjustments to `apache2.conf` and `000-default.conf` and anything in `/etc/apache2/` will require and admin/root user to restart Apache.

Some old school developers *might* say that using `.htaccess` is not a good idea because it will force Apache to load that file on each page load, but on modern systems this is a trivial to non-existent issue. You might save a fraction of a fraction of a fraction of a second on page load if you don’t use `.htaccess`, but that is meaningless nowadays.

If you choose to use it in `.htaccess` there is no need to do something like define it in `<Directory /var/www/html/>` and such. Just create a file called `.htaccess` and make this the contents:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Save it and you are good. Of course, if someone removes, renames or messes around with that file and changes it to `Options +Indexes` directory listings are happening again. But like I said, all these config options depend on need and use; and there is no one best/authoritative way to do this.

But hopefully these options give you ideas on how to approach disabling directory listings in Apache.

Also, regarding the hierarchy of what happens where, if you have a setting in `apache2.conf` and then you have another setting in `000-default.conf` and yet another setting in `.htaccess` then the final edit in `.htaccess` is what matters. You basically want to set all of your reasonable and broad systemwide configs in `apache2.conf` or  `000-default.conf` and then leave the site specific stuff in `.htaccess`.

What matters is the last setting. It’s a cascading pile of settings and honestly *everything* could be in `apache2.conf` but the configs are just split to make your life easier. Instead of one massive monolithic config you could split things out into small files.

Comment: Fantastic description of what each does, thanks @JakeGould.

Comment: Oh, one last question if i may. I'm probably just going to keep my edit in apache2.conf so this will override all the other virtual host stuff going on in 000-default.conf because it supersedes that file, correct?

Comment: Never mind i think you said above "and for all virtual hosts on the machine" .... yep.. so i think that covers it...

Comment: @Supplement Nope. If you have a setting in `apache2.conf` and then you have another setting in `000-default.conf` and yet another setting in `.htaccess` then the final edit in `.htaccess` is what matters. You basically want to set all of your reasonable and broad systemwide configs in `apache2.conf ` or  `000-default.conf` and then leave the site specific stuff in `.htaccess`.